# Returning php string to jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-forms-plugin, jqueryform

i have simple form that uploads image to server and returns php string containing image adress (and/or aditional html code). It is done with JqueryForm plugin. What i want: value (string) that is returned by PHP file needs to be returned to jquery, so i can use that image url to set it as bckground of some element:

Here is php file (for uplaoding image):

$path = "uploads/";

```
$valid_formats = array("jpg", "png", "bmp");
if(isset($_POST) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")
    {
        $name = $_FILES['photoimg']['name'];
        $size = $_FILES['photoimg']['size'];

        if(strlen($name))
            {
                list($txt, $ext) = explode(".", $name);
                if(in_array($ext,$valid_formats))
                {
                if($size<(1024*1024))
                    {
                        $actual_image_name = time().substr(str_replace(" ", "_", $txt), 5).".".$ext;
                        $tmp = $_FILES['photoimg']['tmp_name'];
                        if(move_uploaded_file($tmp, $path.$actual_image_name))
                            {
                                echo $actual_image_name; //This is returned, i want thist to be somehow "converted" to jquery
                            }
                        else
                            echo "Sending failed!";
                    }
                    else
                    echo "May filesize 1 Mb!";                  
                    }
                    else
                    echo "Unknown ffile format!";   
            }

        else
            echo "Select image for sending";

        exit;
    }
```

And, here is jquery code for sending image:

```
$('#photoimg').live('change', function() {
       $("#main").html('');
$("#main").html('<img src="/uploader/loader.gif" class="vk_upload_bar" alt="Uploading...."/>');
$("#imageform").ajaxForm({
        target: '#main'
}).submit();
});
```

Somehow, instead of:

```
target: '#main'
```

that puts some html inside of #main, i need to make this:

```
   $('#main').css('background-image', 'url(' + imageUrl + ')');
```

where image will be assigned ti #main by css. (imageUrl is that string from php file above: $actual_image_name)

Is this possible, or at least is there some similar solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to implement **success** item in jquery form,
you code must be like this
(be sure in php u return full path of image,not need engage himself with json, with echo or print work correctly )

```
$('#photoimg').live('change', function() {
   $("#main").html('');
   $("#main").html('<img src="/uploader/loader.gif" class="vk_upload_bar"       alt="Uploading...."/>');
   $("#imageform").ajaxForm({
    url : 'yourphpfile' ,
   success :function (data){
          $('#main').css('background-image', 'url(' +  data + ')');

    }

   }).submit();
    });
```

for more information about jquery form use [this link](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#ajaxForm)  ,

regards

Comment: Wow, tnx man, works great, but just one more thing, now "loader.gif" image stays there forever, it doesnt hide after upload is finished. Here is what my Opera error console says:             ` [28.5.2012 17:52:55] JavaScript -[28.5.2012 17:52:55] JavaScript - http://domain.com/products-page/product-category/test/
console.log
[jquery.form] state = complete
[28.5.2012 17:52:56] JavaScript - http://domain.com/products-page/product-category/test/
console.log
[jquery.form] isXml=false `

Comment: my friend , for remove  loader.gif you just remove it before change the css 


   success :function (data){
  **$('#main').html('');**
          $('#main').css('background-image', 'url(' +  data + ')');

    }

Comment: Tnx again, i already removed it, i added $('.upload_bar').fadeOut('medium'); :)

Answer (score 2):

Write a function call that executes when the document loads, and pass the string into the function call in the HTML's javascript:

```
$(document).onload( function() {
     functionCall('<?php echo $actual_image_name ?>');
}
```

Comment: Well, no, that php file is not included in file where everythig happens.

Comment: That's all I really got bro. Consider a redesign perhaps? Make the php function return the value, and then on the index page save it as a variable and echo it into the script

Answer (score 1):

Make an AJAX call, which sends the data as a JSON string to a PHP file, and receives the results (also a JSON string) in a callback function. Use the return data in your jQuery.

Comment: Well, it is easier to just return string (from php file), but i dont  know is it possible to do with jquery form plugin i curently use?

Comment: I meant what Zhilevan answered, with the callback function.